# Case When Expression in Different Way

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I need a new column by assigning a value from an existing column in SQL Server.

I want to get `commission2` column according to `commission` amounts.

There are customers which can be included 1 or 2 brands and commission amounts as well.

| Customerid | CountCustomer | Brand | commission | commission2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | B | -28 | 0 |
| **1001** | **2** | **B** | **12** | **12** |
| **1001** | **2** | **F** | **252** | **252** |
| 1002 | 1 | B | 62 | 62 |
| 1003 | 1 | B | 5 | 5 |
| 1004 | 1 | B | -61 | 0 |
| 1005 | 1 | F | 0 | 0 |
| 1006 | 1 | F | 32 | 32 |
| 1007 | 1 | F | 0 | 0 |
| 1008 | 1 | B | -496 | 0 |
| 1009 | 1 | F | 1 | 1 |
| 1010 | 1 | B | 1 | 1 |
| 1011 | 1 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 1012 | 1 | F | -10 | 0 |
| 1013 | 1 | B | 82 | 82 |
| 1014 | 1 | B | 54 | 54 |
| 1015 | 1 | B | 18 | 18 |
| 1016 | 1 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 1017 | 2 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 1017 | 2 | F | -21 | 0 |
| 1018 | 1 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 1019 | 1 | B | 5 | 5 |
| 1020 | 1 | B | -3 | 0 |
| 1021 | 1 | F | -1 | 0 |
| 1022 | 1 | B | 95 | 95 |
| 1023 | 1 | B | -20 | 0 |
| 1024 | 1 | B | 0 | 0 |
| **1025** | **2** | **B** | **-65** | **10** |
| **1025** | **2** | **F** | **10** | **10** |
| **1026** | **2** | **B** | **24** | **24** |
| **1026** | **2** | **F** | **-7** | **24** |
| 1027 | 2 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 1027 | 2 | F | 0 | 0 |

Here are the rules:

- If `CountCustomer = 1` then it is easy. If `commission <= 0` then `commission2` is 0 otherwise it is equal to `commission`
- If `CountCustomer = 2` (means a customer is on 2 brands), and one of the commission amounts > 0 and the other one is < 0, then both `commission2` values should be the number which is positive. If both of the commission numbers are above 0, then these numbers should stay the same for `commission2`. If both commissions are < 0 then commission2 should be 0 for both. You can understand more clear from bolded rows on the table above.

Comment: On a side note: Hopefully, there is no column CountCustomer in your real table. Don't store data redundantly. The number of rows for a customer can easily be read from the table with `count(*)`. There must be no column holding the same (or in the bad case a different) value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use window functions to see the number of entries per customer as well as the minimum and maximum commissions:

```
select 
  customerid,
  count(*) over (partition by customerid) as countcustomer,
  brand,
  commission,
  case 
    when count(*) over (partition by customerid) = 1 then
      case when commission < 0 then 0 else commission end
    else
      case 
        when max(commission) (partition by customerid) <= 0 then
          0
        when min(commission) (partition by customerid) >  0 then
          commission
        else
          max(commission) (partition by customerid)
      end
  end as commission2
from mytable
order by customerid, brand;
```

Or, as the multi-row conditions work for the single-row customers, too, just:

```
select 
  customerid,
  count(*) over (partition by customerid) as countcustomer,
  brand,
  commission,
  case 
    when max(commission) (partition by customerid) <= 0 then
      0
    when min(commission) (partition by customerid) >  0 then
      commission
    else
      max(commission) (partition by customerid)
  end as commission2
from mytable
order by customerid, brand;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that's the logic you're seeking, but if that's what I understood, the CASE WHEN should be like this:

```
SELECT Customerid, CountCustomer, Brand, comission,
         CASE WHEN CountCustomer = 1 AND commission > 0 THEN commision
            WHEN CountCustomer = 1 AND commission < 0 THEN 0
            WHEN CountCustomer = 2 AND commission > 0 THEN comission
            WHEN CountCustomer = 2 AND commission < 0 THEN 0
            END AS commission2
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: This code doesn't work well for CountCustomer=2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Customerid  
    ,CountCustomer  
    ,Brand  
    ,commission
    CASE WHEN CountCustomer = 1 AND commission >= 0 THEN commission
         WHEN CountCustomer = 2 AND commission > 0 AND commission2 < 0 THEN commission
         WHEN CountCustomer = 2 AND commission < 0 AND commission2 > 0 THEN commission2
         WHEN CountCustomer = 2 AND commission < 0 AND commission2 < 0 THEN 0   
    ELSE commission2 AS 'commission2'
FROM MyTable
```

I tried my best to follow your explanation. You can modify the statements as you need them. This should return the column **commission2** as you want it.

Comment: I think that was my fault, commission2 should be required column I want to create.

Comment: @Veli K: So you should edit your request and put this information above the table.